# Fail to compile erlang r14b03

Tags: build, erlang

I'm having trouble building erlang (r14b03) on Mac OS Lion.  I've had these same issues (exact same trace) trying to install erlang on Crunchbang Linux - and I'm totally confused.  Here is the error I'm getting:

```
...
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make -f i386-apple-darwin11.3.0/Makefile TYPE=opt
llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -O3  -m64 -O0 -I/Users/john/.kerl/builds/r14b03/otp_src_R14B03/erts/i386-apple-darwin11.3.0  -no-cpp-precomp  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -DUSE_THREADS -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -DPOSIX_THREADS -DERLANG_INTEGRATION  -o /Users/john/.kerl/builds/r14b03/otp_src_R14B03/erts/emulator/pcre/obj/i386-apple-darwin11.3.0/opt/pcre_exec.o pcre_exec.c
pcre_exec.c: In function ‘match’:
pcre_exec_loop_break_cases.inc:44: error: label ‘L_LOOP_COUNT_47’ used but not defined
pcre_exec_loop_break_cases.inc:43: error: label ‘L_LOOP_COUNT_46’ used but not defined
...
pcre_exec_loop_break_cases.inc:3: error: label ‘L_LOOP_COUNT_6’ used but not defined
pcre_exec_loop_break_cases.inc:2: error: label ‘L_LOOP_COUNT_5’ used but not defined
pcre_exec_loop_break_cases.inc:1: error: label ‘L_LOOP_COUNT_4’ used but not defined
make[5]: *** [/Users/john/.kerl/builds/r14b03/otp_src_R14B03/erts/emulator/pcre/obj/i386-apple-darwin11.3.0/opt/pcre_exec.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[3]: *** [pcre] Error 2
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[1]: *** [smp] Error 2
make: *** [emulator] Error 2
```

I'm using kerl (although I've also tried without it), and the following `.kerlrc`:

```
CFLAGS=-O0
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--enable-hipe --enable-smp-support --enable-threads --enable-kernel-poll  --enable-darwin-64bit"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See [how to add env variables for building Erlang in kerl](https://github.com/spawngrid/kerl/issues/49) - using shell export command inside .kerlrc will help.

Comment: This answer supersedes the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess trying [Building a fast Erlang VM on Mac OS Lion (from the Installation Guide)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#id70692) will help.